# fastlane: command not found in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: ios, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, fastlane

I'm using the Jenkins pipeline to check out my code, build and release my app using the HockeyApp tool. For all the above steps I want to use Fastlane commands and they should be executed using shell script in declarative pipeline syntax. How can I achieve this? Below is my declarative pipeline script.

Where should I configure the Fastlane path? Should it be done inside Jenkins configuration or somewhere else? Please help me out.

Thanks

```
  pipeline {
      agent any

       stages {
            stage('First Stage Cocoapods Install') {
                steps {
                echo 'Hi, this is first jenkins pipeline stage.'
             /*checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'Bitbucket', url: 'https://********@bitbucket.org/*****/******.git']]])*/

                // Mark the cocoapods 'stage'....
                 sh "fastlane pods"   

                }
            }

            stage('Second Stage Build the App') {
                steps {
                echo 'Hi, this is Second jenkins pipeline stage.'
                sh "fastlane gym"
                }
            }
            stage('Three Stage') {
                steps {
                echo 'Hi, this is Third jenkins pipeline stage.'
                }
            }

            stage('Four Stage') {
                steps {
                echo 'Hi, this is fourth jenkins pipeline stage.'
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: This can help - https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/continuous-integration/

Comment: When you write 'configure', what do you mean? If your project has a `Gemfile` that first stage should be "Install dependencies" and include a `bundle install`. Then, `fastlane` should be available to run via `bundle exec fastlane ....`

Comment: I'm having this same issue, have you found a solution?